# Binding to Ldap Server using ldap_bind_s- Can we authenticate using usertoken rathen than username and password

Tags: authentication, ldap

I use ldap_bind_s to bind to ldap server.
example:

SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY *pSecIdentity;

ldap_bind_s(    pLdapConnection,      // Session Handle
                    NULL,                // Domain DN
                    (_TCHAR*)pSecIdentity,     // Credential structure
                    LDAP_AUTH_NEGOTIATE)

pSecIdentity is filled with username and password.
But the problem is i want to do the same with PKI users where i dont have username and password instead a user token. 
So how to proceed with this scenario.
Are there any Structure to provide usertoken instead of username/password to authenticate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this helps 
Not very sure but looks promising
https://pkienthusiast.wordpress.com/2011/09/16/apache2-pki-certificate-authentication-and-ldap-authorisation-example-2/